# Easiest way to paginate a large table - circa 3000 rows

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, datatables

Im working on a web-app project and on one of my pages i have a very large table, circa 2000 rows.

Im looking for the simplest way to provide a pagination feature to this table to allow say 50 or 100 rows be viewed at a time. I have looked at  http://www.datatables.net/ but it doesnt seem to be working for me,

Are there any other simple options out there?

Cheers

Comment: Why jQuery datatables doesn't work for you ?

Comment: Im getting an error: DataTables warning (table id = 'invalidDataTable'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0 when i load the page, I am trying to find a simple full example of using datatables but none sem to go through the process fully.

Comment: what datasource are you using? Is it an javascript array or a ajax returned json? both cannot contain null values. Replace them with empty strings: "". Please show us your initialization code. Datatables should be perfect for this.

Comment: Its actually an application that uses backbone.js, the data fromat being retrieved is JSON so im now investigating using Backgrid.js